# ASP.NET Core 2.0 EventLog change Application name in Event Viewer

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core-2.0, event-log, event-viewer

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog` to log to Windows Event Viewer with

```
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
  logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
  logging.AddEventLog();
  logging.AddConsole();
})
```

On Event Viewer I can see my application working and logging itself to it, but it has the default name of Application under Source, and I'm trying to figure out on how to change it's name so it can Log under a different source name.

Comment: It would be a good idea in the future to check the documentation, as you could have found your answer faster and without taking up anyone else's time had you done a little research.

Answer (score 5):

You can control that by passing an [EventLogSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.eventlog.eventlogsettings?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to the [extension method that adds logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.eventloggerfactoryextensions.addeventlog?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

```
var eventLogSettings = new EventLogSettings
{
    LogName = "Something",
    SourceName = "Something 2"
};

logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings);
```

Comment: Can we make the LogName and SourceName to be read from appSettings.json file?

Comment: @Quest sure, why not?

Comment: Can you tell, how can we read Log and Source name from appSettings.json file?

Comment: @Quest Feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: i tried that, but still logging on Application. Do you know what happening?

Comment: @BrunoHenri If you tried it, and it's still not working ask a new question.